# Java Metric Unit Conversion Library?

Tags: java

I have an application that will need to perform a number of unit conversions (metric to Imperial, Imperial to metric).

Is there an existing Java library that does this?  Or will I need to roll my own?  (My initial Google searches proved moderately useless.)

Comment: You could take a look at this https://github.com/mbe24/sius by now it supports meter, mile for length and kilogram, pound for mass. It supports addition and does *implicit* type conversion. It is statically typed, so conversion errors are visibile at compile time :) I will add more features :)

Answer (score 58):

there is a specific [JSR 275](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=275) (javax.measure) with [JScience](http://jscience.org/) as RI (Reference Implementation). For example converting 100 Miles to kilometers is easy as:

```
UnitConverter toKilometers = MILE.getConverterTo(KILOMETER);
double km = toKilometers.convert(Measure.valueOf(100, MILE).doubleValue(MILE));
```

(note that units are all type safe a compile-time, a killer feature imho)

The reverse can be easy:

```
UnitConverter toMiles1 = KILOMETER.getConverterTo(MILE);
```

or supereasy as:

```
UnitConverter toMiles2 = toKilometers.inverse();
```

NB imports:

```
import javax.measure.Measure;
import javax.measure.converter.UnitConverter;
import javax.measure.quantity.Length;
import static javax.measure.unit.NonSI.*;
import static javax.measure.unit.SI.*;
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I had never heard of this but will be extremely useful in my work.

Comment: Very nice, but the request was rejected and I downloaded JScience 5.0 and couldn't find an implementation like the one in the example shown here. Can anyone point to how this can be accomplished now?

Comment: JScience seems good, but i am not able to find proper documentation for that it has well documented API but i am looking for some thing like Wiki, if you have any links let me know :D

Comment: It's been relocated to github: https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement

Comment: Gradle dependency `implementation 'org.jscience:jscience:4.3.1'`

Comment: On Android I needed to exclude `Javolution` as noted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841614/2625236


`compile ('org.jscience:jscience:4.3.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.javolution', module: 'javolution'
}`

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jscience/jscience/4.3.1  (continuation of Vlad's comment)

Answer (score 4):

We created a library, [UnitOf](https://digidemic.github.io/UnitOf/), for Java, JavaScript, and C# to easily perform these measurement conversions. There are are over 20 complete units of measure and conversions can be done in as little as one line.

```
//One liner
double x = new UnitOf.Mass().fromPounds(5).toKilograms(); //2.26796 returned as 5 pounds is 2.26796 kilograms

//Or as a variable
UnitOf.Length feet = new UnitOf.Length().fromFeet(5.5); //Instantiate UnitOf.Length and set "feet" as 5.5
double foo = feet.toInches(); //66 returned as 5.5 feet is 66 inches
double bar = feet.toMeters(); //1.6764 returned as 5.5 feet is 1.6764 meters
```

UnitOf also gives the ability to parse data types, convert to and from fractions, and even create your own custom UnitOf measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the pile...

Unidata now publishes the java units conversion library from [netcdf-java](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/) as a [standalone package](https://artifacts.unidata.ucar.edu/content/repositories/unidata-releases/edu/ucar/udunits/).

Answer (score -2):

I have found [Java Unit Conversion library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jucl/) at SourceForge, but I have not yet tried it (I will need similar funcionality in near future). It is licensed as BSD license. It might help.

Comment: But sorry, it seems, it is already dead for a long time and has not documentation... I replied too quickly without looking at it.