# Java - JScience define a new unit

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jscience

I want to define a new distance unit in [JScience](http://jscience.org/api/overview-summary.html#TUTORIAL). The "Tutorial" section of the project website just leads to Javadoc which, while fairly complete, is a bit too dense for me to fathom how I actually go about defining my own unit.

Could you provide an example?

Cheers.

Pete

Comment: Doesn't look like too many people use JScience.  Perhaps you'll have to write the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193810/java-metric-unit-conversion-library) about units in Java can help.

Comment: Didn't help for me, because there is no clear info how to add new unit.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but.. i'm going to post the answer anyways, maybe it'll be useful to someone

In order to define a custom unit in JScience, you have to extend the class `SystemOfUnits` and define here all your custom units.

Check the exemple below (i'm defining the unit for ACREs)

```
public class MyUnits extends SystemOfUnits 
{
   private static HashSet<Unit<?>> UNITS = new HashSet();

   private static final MyUnits INSTANCE = new MyUnits();

   public static final Unit<Area> ACRE = myUnits((SI.METER.pow(2)).times(4046.8564224).asType(Area.class));

   public static MyUnits getInstance()
   {
      return INSTANCE;
   }    

   @Override
   public Set<Unit<?>> getUnits()
   {
      return Collections.unmodifiableSet(UNITS);
   }

   private static <U extends Unit<?>> U myUnits(U unit)
   {
      UNITS.add(unit);
      return unit;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same question too.. I looked at their docs and I think what we need is http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/UnitFormat.html (label method), but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at how JSR 363 RI does this (the successor to 275 which was implemented by JScience 4)
https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri/blob/master/src/main/java/tec/units/ri/format/SimpleUnitFormat.java

The default flavor of SimpleUnitFormat supports UTF-8, while ASCII is for limited environments or devices that may have no GUI or limited character sets:

`DEFAULT.label(MetricPrefix.MICRO(Units.LITRE), "µl");
ASCII.label(MetricPrefix.MICRO(Units.LITRE), "microL");`

Note, the label() method will be introduced to JSR 363 API in the next candidate release for Public Draft. Currently it's part of the RI (https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri, not JScience, though it may eventually migrate to the new standard, too in V5)